# Microsoft Excel 2016 new Column with part of another column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column that contains text of varying lengths.  I need to create a new column that contains only the text before the first space in the string.  So, example in column A I have:

```
76T VENDOR UNASSIGNED XXXXXX TO LOB

CR18D PEND-REVIEW OF DUPLICATE CODES
```

I want to add Column B that would be:

```
76T

CR18D
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [LEFT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LEFT-LEFTB-functions-9203D2D2-7960-479B-84C6-1EA52B99640C) and [FIND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FIND-FINDB-functions-C7912941-AF2A-4BDF-A553-D0D89B0A0628):

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1 & " ")-1)
```

As @Jeeped pointed out the `& " "` will avoid an error if no space is found and return the whole string.